# Dealing with country names Python

Tags: python

I'm dealing with parsing country names coming from google analytics and I must get the country code for a prebid module to set the country's region based on it's code. I have tried the following:

```
from iso3166 import countries_by_name, Country
    
country_code = []
for key in countries_by_name.keys():
    pattern = country_name_from_google_analytics
    match = re.search(pattern, key, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        
    if match:
       country_code = countries_by_name.get(key, [])
    if isinstance(country_code, Country):
       break #get only the first result?
```

The problem appears when I try to deal with a country name like Côte d’Ivoire which is returned by google like that but in the ISO3166 the same country appears as Côte d'Ivoire (notice the change in the uptick). Other examples are things like Myanmar (Burma) (GA) and Myanmar [Burma].
I would like to know if there is a way to get something like a partial regular expression match or a way to deal with those small differences.

Comment: If the names are not too long, you can use levenshtein distance between the names and then find the minimum. Basically, you are finding how different are two strings and then selecting the one which is the least different.

Comment: Remove all punctuation from compared strings. Compare `re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', country_name_from_google_analytics)` with `re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', key)`  (or `regex.sub(r'\p{P}', '', key)` using [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Levenshtein is certainly an option (difficult due to false positives), but since you're dealing with 2 standardized versions of country name, which as far as we can tell can only differ by either special character, or by non-English letter it should be enough to remove these and check then:

```py
def comp_country_name(c1:str, c2:str) -> bool:
    patt = re.compile("[^a-z]")
    c1, c2 = patt.sub("", c1.lower()), patt.sub("", c2.lower())
    matched = 0
    total = min(len(c1), len(c2))
    for i in range(total):
        if c1[i] == c2[i]:
            matched += 1
    return 0 if total==0 else matched/total > 0.9
```

Which for your examples will return:

```py
args =["Côte d’Ivoire", "Côte d'Ivoire", "Myanmar (Burma)", "Myanmar [Burma]"]

for el1 in args:
    for el2 in args:
        print(el1, el2)
        print(comp_country_name(el1, el2))
```

Output:

```
Côte d’Ivoire Côte d’Ivoire
True
Côte d’Ivoire Côte d'Ivoire
True
Côte d’Ivoire Myanmar (Burma)
False
Côte d’Ivoire Myanmar [Burma]
False
Côte d'Ivoire Côte d’Ivoire
True
Côte d'Ivoire Côte d'Ivoire
True
Côte d'Ivoire Myanmar (Burma)
False
Côte d'Ivoire Myanmar [Burma]
False
Myanmar (Burma) Côte d’Ivoire
False
Myanmar (Burma) Côte d'Ivoire
False
Myanmar (Burma) Myanmar (Burma)
True
Myanmar (Burma) Myanmar [Burma]
True
Myanmar [Burma] Côte d’Ivoire
False
Myanmar [Burma] Côte d'Ivoire
False
Myanmar [Burma] Myanmar (Burma)
True
Myanmar [Burma] Myanmar [Burma]
True
```